# How to set a hardware watchpoint in dbx?

Tags: c++, gdb, solaris, dbx, watchpoint

I need to detect when some memory changes in dbx on Solaris.  I know in gdb that I would do this with `watch <memoryLocation>`.  However, I am using dbx at the moment, so I need to know how to set a hardware watchpoint in dbx.  What is the dbx command to set a hardware watchpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is answered here:
[How do you put a breakpoint on a memory location in dbx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351052/how-do-you-put-a-breakpoint-on-a-memory-location-in-dbx)

It's the same for C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

`dbx` is the standard debugger on Solaris and AIX; these debuggers are different, and you didn't say which one you are actually using.

This Google [query](https://www.google.com/search?q=dbx%20hardware%20watchpoint) produces an answer for [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/wrkshp50/805-4948/z400055837ac/index.html) and [AIX](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/dbx.htm).